# Why can't I respond with output from child process in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, express

I am using Node JS with Express and trying to execute a script and return the output of that script to the client via AJAX. The script is completing successfully, but for some reason I cannot get the output to show in the post response.

```
let childProcess = require('child_process');

router.post('/update', (req, res) => {
    childProcess.exec('/home/dir/app/update.sh', { shell: '/bin/bash' }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        res.json({ error, stdout, stderr });
    });
});
```

The Node process is run using Forever. If I look at the forever log, it shows:

> Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL

Not sure what that means. It appears the script is completing successfully though.

**EDIT**
To address Aikon's answer below. I tried the following and still no go.

```
router.post('/update', (req, res) => {
    console.log('start...');

    childProcess.exec('/home/dir/app/update.sh', { shell: '/bin/bash' }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log('done');

        error = error || '';
        stdout = stdout || '';
        stderr = stderr || '';

        res.json({ error, stdout, stderr });
    });
});
```

It's as if the success function is never firing because it never logs "done" in the console. It just logs "start..." and the SIGKILL error above in the console.

Comment: you'll have to consider using [execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) since it's a file

Comment: What does `update.sh` look like? Your code works for me with a simple bash script. (Y'know, unless there's other routes that might be conflicting that you didn't mention)

Comment: Here are the lines from update.sh, shebang at the top... #!/bin/bash, git pull, npm install, npm run build, forever restartall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script kill(and restart) itself **before** it can read output from child process.

Look at your `update.sh` again:

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull
npm install
npm run build

#this command restarts your script
forever restartall
```

You could remove last line of `update.sh`, and after sending response, the script just exits, `forever` should restart it with updated version.

```
router.post('/update', (req, res) => {
  childProcess.exec('/home/dir/app/update.sh', { shell: '/bin/bash' }, 
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    res.json({ error, stdout, stderr });
    process.exit();
  });
});
```

Comment: 1. Totally awesome. 2. I can't believe I didn't realize this, now I feel dumb!

Answer (score 1):

1. If error is not empty then output is undefined => fail
2. After stringify error is empty object.

---

```
'use strict';
let error = new Error('err');
let str = 'text';
let obj = {a: 10, b: 15}; // Try comment to get fall
console.log(JSON.stringify({error, str, obj}))
```

Comment: see my edit above to address this answer... no luck.

Comment: You can try to do: 1. Turn off Forever and see console; 2. Replace callback function to one line `res.json({})` (perhaps it's not reason to fault); 3. `error = error || '';` don't do it because you lost error message; 4. Simplify `update.sh` to one line e.g. echo 'ok'. Also verify that `update.sh` is accessable and you have permission to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code. Try:

```
res.json({ error: error, output: stdout, error_log: stderr });
```

alternatively you can do:

```
res.json([ error, stdout, stderr ]);
```

Comment: that syntax is part of ES6

Comment: @WayOfTheFuture: Ah, but my solution will still fix your code. Only my explanation may be wrong. See Aikon's answer for why this will fix your code.